# Objeto Map en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda en un objeto Map de JavaScript se puede agregar elementos repetidos? Es decir si quiero ingresar el nombre, edad y función de n numero de empleados ¿puedo usar Map ? 
Aclaro me refiero al object Map no a la funcion es decir a esto:
let users =  new Map();

Comment: Hola Erik, es importante realices el [tour] del sitio y revises [ask] que te brinda información para realizar preguntas en el sitio, por favor lee los documentos, saludos!

Comment: @Erik Andres Un `Map` no te permite ingresar valores repetidos ten presente que se conoce como diccinario de datos de tipo [llave, valor], por lo tanto si ingresas una llave igual, sobreescribiras el valor anterior; revisate la `MDN` en la sección de `Map`

Answer (score 1):

La funcion MAP es un especie de forEach que no solo recorre cada elemento del array, si no que crea 1 nuevo por cada uno.

Entonces podrias estar usandolo para agregar a todos los datos que tenes, esos campos que te faltan.

Ejemplo

```
let usuarios = [{nombre:"pepe"},{nombre:"maria"}];

usuarios = usuarios.map(user => ({...user,edad:19}));

console.log(usuarios);
```

Para mas info sobre MAP, visita este [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

Comment: Me parece tu código tiene un error, pues así regresa un error de tipo `"SyntaxError: Rest parameter must be last formal parameter` indicando que el parámetro `rest` debería ser el último de la declaración

Comment: @Aprendiz Tenes mucha razon, me confundi al agregar los { } , ya lo solucione :D , muchas gracias!!

Comment: No me refiero a la funcion map sino al objeto Map de ES6 es decir a esto  let usuarios=new Map()